# Percent change for nonlinear data

Tags: time-series, econometrics, computational-statistics

My professor said that percent change between two data points in a nonlinear data set doesn't make sense, as, it can be shown that the percent change between two adjacent points in a time series is proportional to the slope. I.e, 
$pc = \Delta y / y_1 = m \Delta t / y_1 \approx m / y_1$, since $\Delta t = 1$ for two adjacent points.

Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe your professor is saying that for nonlinear data, the percent change between two adjacent data points depends on the data points, rather than being the same for all adjacent data points.  I'm not sure exactly what "nonlinear data" is, but I guess it could be time series data such that the percent change is not the same for all adjacent data points, i.e., that don't lie along a line. If so, the statement would be true as a (reasonable) tautology.

Comment: What's a *nonlinear data set*?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and no. If the x and y errors are proportional type, then taking the logs of both the x and y data will increase the goodness-of-fit and the correlation coefficient of a nonlinear function to the data, compared to those from the linear plot. However, that does not mean that that a departure from linearity in one section of the curve has the same relative worth as it would in some other portion of the curve, but then, so what? So, your professor is correct, but that does not mean that we would not model the data as proportional type. Or if you wish, if the shoe fits....